# What is the time complexity of splitting an array in 2

Tags: algorithm, memory-management, time, split, complexity-theory

What is the time complexity of splitting an array in 2; Is it O(1) because it is down directly by manipulating memory or O(N) as it has to loop through the entire array. And if the last is correct, is there a way to manipulate directly to memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how you split it.

If you do it by copying the halves of the array its O(N)

If you do it by using a pointer like `int* x = &a[n/2];` then its O(1)

Comment: Thanks! But that means I need to use a language with pointers, right? I can't prototype it in Python maybe?

Comment: Not directly, you can do pointer copies of things in python using the copy library https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: @MitchelPaulin int* x = a[n/2] is correct for an array of pointer. If it's an array of ints, then it should be int x = a[n/2] or int* x = &a[n/2]